# Text only rotating banner

Tags: 6, blocks, media

Is there any module for drupal 6 I can use to create a rotating banner with no images for drupal 6 site

Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Marquee Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/marquee_block) module

> Provides a jQuery-based scrolling marquee block that can be customized with your own text or HTML. Configure speed, scroll direction and scroll behavior easily on the Block setup page.

Image from module page:

[image]

Or else if you want to do it so simple. just create a block and use `<marquee>` in your custom block ;)